# How to setup a Windows user with remote Documents path?

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, path

I am a freelance developer, recently some customers are complaining that my app breaks when their Windows `Documents` folders locate on a remote path in cooperate network, not locally.

Here are the two example `Documents` path:

```
\\FILESERVER\Profiles\User1\Documents\
\\main.some.org\site$\Home\Dev\8\User2\Documents\
```

I would like to reproduce the problem on similar environments.

**Question:**
How could I setup a Windows user with such remote `Documents` path?

Comment: This is called folder redirection. You can change the location of a special folder, like my documents, by simply right-clicking it and looking at its properties or dragging and dropping it to a new location. If you don’t have a second computer to share a network path from, you can just create and share a folder from your local computer and then redirect the my documents folder to the UNC path of the local share. I.e. `\\localhost\SomeFolder`

Comment: If folder redirection is breaking your program it’s typically because you have made an assumption about folder paths. Instead we allow windows to tell us where these folders are. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shldisp/ne-shldisp-shellspecialfolderconstants?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Thanks! I could redirect Documents to my NAS share now.